# SQL query to retrieve unique record based on role and email fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to retrieve some records based on my requirement. As per the current table, a store can have any number of managers and/or cashiers with their respective email addresses. Now, I am trying to retrieve a new set of records which will have only one manager and/or one cashier per branch with their respective email address (there are no criteria to pick up specific manager cashier)

Current table:

```
BranchName      Role        Email
-------------------------------------------------
CA              Cashier     Cashier1@gmail.com
CA              Cashier     Cashier2@gmail.com
NY              Manager     Manager1@gmail.com
NY              Manager     Manager2@gmail.com
MASS            Manager     Manager@gmail.com
MASS            Manager     Massm@gmail.com
```

Expected output:

```
BranchName      Role        Email
------------------------------------------------
CA              Cashier     Cashier1@gmail.com
NY              Manager     Manager1@gmail.com
MASS            Manager     massm@gmail.com
```

The output is based on the requirement that, branch to Role is one to one mapping whereas Role to branch is one- many ( role and email forms a uniqueness for that particular branch).

I have tried using the below query but I am able to see the duplicate roles for  a single branch.

```
select 
    BranchName, Email, Role
from 
    (select 
         BranchName, Email, Role,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Role ORDER BY Email) AS "C" 
     from 
         Store
     where 
         Role IN ('Manager', 'General manager', 'Cashier')
    )
where 
    C = 1;
```

In my above query, while partitioning by role it only display single record with single branch instead of single role for all branches. It could be because of the condition C=1, if I remove this, I am getting all the records.

I hope, I have provided enough details. Kindly provide some inputs to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a preference/rule for choosing an email address given a branch name and role, then you just do a simple `GROUP BY` to get a result:

```
SELECT BranchName,
       Role,
       MIN(Email) AS Email
FROM Store
GROUP BY BranchName,
         Role
```